# Run script right after adding a specific Gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

How to run a script right after adding a block? I'm adding map block using ServerSideRender but it only prints div with map id map-canvas. I want to apply

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas')
```

How I would apply it after map block is added?